# Can I show python code comments as markdown in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

Is there an extension which will allow you to convert this:

```
# A code *comment*
v = and_associated_code()
v
```

To be displayed in the next output cell as first the rendered markdown for `A code *comment*` and then the output of the second line?

Main use-case is for convenience when the markdown blocks are too small.

It'd be even better, though not required, if there is a way to only show some comments / comments in some cells like this and leave the others with their default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @manisar's answer, I came up with a simple IPython magic that allows you to use an IPython / Juptyer notebook code cell to display markdown contained in the cell as a formatted string or f-string/string literal: [`fstring-magic`](https://github.com/innovationOUtside/fstring-magic)

Install as `pip install git+https://github.com/innovationOUtside/fstring-magic.git` and then load as `load_ext fstring_magic`.

There are two block magics: `%%stringformat` to run a simple string formatter over the contents of the cell using the local scope and then display an HTML formatted markdown output, and `%%fstring` to treat the contents of the cell as an f-string in the local scope.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following, not exactly doing what is asked, is a possible workaround. Until we get the requested extension, this may be used.

The code below will show **markdown in IPython from within code cells**, while ignoring it when run in normal Python (like usual comments). The constraint is to use strings instead of comments.

**Note:** I used forbiddenfruit just for aesthetics, that is not a requirement.

```
import sys
from IPython.display import display, Markdown # check link at the end for improved code
from forbiddenfruit import curse
def display_string(self):
    if 'ipykernel' in sys.modules: display(Markdown(self))
curse(str, "md", display_string)
```

I placed the above in a separate file, and then I import it anywhere I need it.
After this, the following code (e.g.), when run as a normal script ignores the string-comments:

```
import numpy as np
r = 5
h = 20
volume = np.pi * r**2 * h
"""Thus we have calculated the **volume** of the *cylinder* by using the formula
$$ V = \pi r^2 h $$""".md()
"Now we'll calcualte the area as per $A = \pi r^2 + 2 \pi r h$.".md()
A = np.pi * r**2 + 2 * np.pi * r * h
```

but when run in IPython, displays this (alongside executing the python code):

```
Thus we have calculated the volume of the cylinder by using the formula
                                V = πr2h
Now we'll calculate the area as per A = πr2 + 2πrh.
```

Considering that triple quoted strings are often used as multiline comments, this solution may be useful in many scenarios, and will not be a significant deviation from using normal comments.

On the plus side, there are two **advantages**:

1. We get fine level control by having the option to decide **exactly which comments** (strings) are shown in the output (as was desired in the question).
2. We can include **dynamic values** in the markdown, generated by code execution at run time by using f-strings (courtesy @psychemedia - the comment below) .

***Update***: *I created a github package with improved code and extra options that can be installed with `pip`. Check [github](https://github.com/manisar2/ipyccmd).
Or you may copy the code.*

Comment: You can also treat the multiline comment as an f-string which allows you to get code outputs inline into the displayed formatted markdown.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea, I had to add it to the answer, hope you won't mind. The magics you created will be useful. I was looking for something like this!